# MySQL select in same table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, self-join

What is the right `SELECT`syntax for my request?

Table:

```
ID / PARENT_ID / THIRD_ID
60 / 0  / 123
61 / 60 / 345
62 / 61 / 567
63 / 61 / 789
```

My request: Show all `THIRD_PARENT_ID`s generated by `ID`s and `PARENT_ID`s. I.e. has entry with `id` = `62` the `parent_id` = `61` and entry with `id` = `61` has the `third_id` =  `345`:

```
THIRD_ID / THIRD_PARENT_ID
60 / -
61 / 123
62 / 345
63 / 345
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT t.id, t2.third_id 
FROM table AS t
LEFT JOIN table AS t2 ON (t2.id = t.parent_id)
```